# Shiny + networkD3 Mouseover Edges to Display Included Vector

Tags: r, shiny, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I'm looking to create tooltips that appear on mouseover in `networkD3` plots in Shiny. In the example below, I've used `twitteR` to allow the Shiny app users to generate data from a `twitteR` search, and I've used `graphTweets` to create a `networkD3` compatible edge list that contains the source screenName, the target screenName, and the text of the tweet. I then pass this edgelist to `simpleNetwork`.

I've shown in the example below how to bind hyperlinks to twitter accounts to `clickAction`. I've also added a list in the network graph that contains the text from each tweet associated with each link. Is there R or JS code I can use to display this text on mouseover on each link?

```r
library(shiny)
library(networkD3)
library(twitteR)
library(graphTweets)
library(dplyr)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput("searchkw", "Search:"),
    actionButton("btn", "Click to Generate")
  ),
  mainPanel(simpleNetworkOutput("network"))
)))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  #Set up twitteR OAuth
  consumer_key <- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  consumer_secret <- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  access_token <- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  access_secret <- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)

  edges <- eventReactive(input$btn, {
    #search twitter, convert to dataframe, and get edges with text vector
    tw.edges <- twListToDF(searchTwitter(input$searchkw)) %>%
     getEdges(tweets = "text", source = "screenName", str.length = NULL, "text")
    tw.edges$text <- sapply(tw.edges$text, function(row) iconv(row, "latin1", "ASCII", sub = "")) #convert text to useable format
    return(tw.edges)
  })

  output$network <- renderSimpleNetwork({
    sn <- simpleNetwork(edges()) #Create simplenetwork graph
    sn$x$nodes$link <- paste0('https://twitter.com/', sn$x$nodes$name) #Add links to twitter accounts to nodes
    sn$x$options$clickAction = 'window.open(d.link)' #Bind node clicks to links
    sn$x$links$text <- edges()$text #Add text as links property
    #How to bind to mouse over/out??#
    return(sn)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: As one of the active developers of networkD3, I don't recommend doing this kind of stuff... it was not designed to allow for that level of customization, and therefore any code like this is not supported and can easily break in the future as we make changes. That being said... 1) you should use forceNetwork as it is more customizable (in fact, simpleNetwork now uses the same underlying JS but with less tie in with its arguments. 2) for tooltips, I would look into using htmltools::htmlDependency to add CSS and/or an JS library like tipsy

Answer (score 2):

This is not officially supported, but you can achieve it by adding some JavaScript with `htmlwidgets::onRender`...

```
library(shiny)
library(networkD3)
library(twitteR)
library(graphTweets)
library(dplyr)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput("searchkw", "Search:"),
    actionButton("btn", "Click to Generate")
  ),
  mainPanel(simpleNetworkOutput("network"))
)))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  #Set up twitteR OAuth
  consumer_key <- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  consumer_secret <- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  access_token <- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  access_secret <- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)

  edges <- eventReactive(input$btn, {
    #search twitter, convert to dataframe, and get edges with text vector
    tw.edges <- twListToDF(searchTwitter(input$searchkw)) %>%
      getEdges(tweets = "text", source = "screenName", str.length = NULL, "text")
    tw.edges$text <- sapply(tw.edges$text, function(row) iconv(row, "latin1", "ASCII", sub = "")) #convert text to useable format
    return(tw.edges)
  })

  output$network <- renderSimpleNetwork({
    sn <- simpleNetwork(edges()) #Create simplenetwork graph
    sn$x$nodes$link <- paste0('https://twitter.com/', sn$x$nodes$name) #Add links to twitter accounts to nodes
    sn$x$options$clickAction = 'window.open(d.link)' #Bind node clicks to links
    sn$x$links$text <- edges()$text #Add text as links property

    # add onRender JavaScript to set the title to the value of 'text' for each link
    sn <- htmlwidgets::onRender(
      sn,
      '
      function(el, x) {
      d3.selectAll(".link")
        .append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
      }
      '
    )

    return(sn)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```